# Why is there a 'true' statement as precondition in the following loop invariant

Tags: loop-invariants

> Precondition: true 
> int i = 0; 
> while (i < a.length && a[i] != x) {
> i++;
> }
> Postcondition: (∀ j : 0 ≤ j < i : a[j] ≠ x) ⋀ (i = a.length ∨ a[i] = x) }

As I read it, the program has no precondition to be established, thus the precondition is always true? Is it like an indicator: "This program has no precondition"?

Comment: You have answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program does have a precondition: `true`. Which means that it is fulfilled, regardless the state variables.

The annotation would still be correct with a stronger precondition, such as `a.length > 0`. `true`cannot be weakened, so it is the weakest precondition.

Comment: But true & a.length > 0 would only be true if a.length > 0.  If a.length > 0 is the precondition it wouldn't make sense to use true as precondition too?

Comment: @Rubus: true is a valid precondition and so is a.length > 0. Besides this, I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: I understand it now. I though you meant true AND a.length > 0 need to be true which would render true useless since the truth value of the statement would then only depend on a.length > 0.  I'm sorry I find this topic confusing...

Comment: @Rubus: I never wrote true AND a.length > 0 (nor with && nor $\land$).